# Question on Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Linear Regression

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

I am studying a [Tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/xiuming/www/docs/tutorials/ReML.pdf) on Maximum Likelihood Estimation in Linear Regression and I have a question.

> When we have more than one regressor (a.k.a. multiple linear regression1), the model comes in its matrix form
>   $y = X\beta + \epsilon$, (1)where $y$ is the response vector, $X$ is the design matrix with each its row specifying under what design or conditions the corresponding response is observed (hence the name), $\beta$ is the vector of regression coefficients, and $\epsilon$ is the residual vector distributing as a zero-mean multivariable Gaussian with a diagonal covariance matrix $\mathcal{N} \sim (0, \sigma^2I_N )$, where $I_N$ is the $N \times N$ identity matrix. Therefore
>   $y \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta,\sigma^2 I_N)$, 
>   (2)meaning that linear combination $X\beta$ explains (or predicts) response y with uncertainty characterized by a variance of $\sigma^2$.
>
> Assume $y, \beta$, and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R^n}$
>   Under the model assumptions, we aim to estimate the unknown parameters ($\beta$ and $\sigma^2$) from the data available ($X$ and $y$).
>
> Maximum likelihood (ML) estimation is the most common estimator. We maximize the log-likelihood w.r.t. $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$
>   $\mathcal{L}(\beta,\sigma^2|y,X)=−\frac{N}{2}\log{2\pi}−\frac{N}{2}log{\sigma^2}− \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y−X\beta)^T(y−X\beta)$.

I am trying to understand that how the log-likelihood, $\mathcal{L}(\beta,\sigma^2|y,X)$, is formed.  Normally, I saw these problems when we have $\mathbf{x_i}$ as vector of size d(d is number of parameter for each data). specifically, when $\mathbf{x_i}$ is a vector, I wrote is as $\ln \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt { (2\pi)^d\boldsymbol \sigma^2 } }  \exp\left(-{1 \over 2\sigma^2} (\mathbf{x_i}-\boldsymbol\mu)^{\rm T} \boldsymbol ({\mathbf x_i}-\boldsymbol\mu)\right) = \sum\limits{_{i}}\ln{\frac{1}{\sqrt { (2\pi)^d\boldsymbol \sigma^2 } }  \exp\left(-{1 \over 2\sigma^2} (\mathbf{x_i}-\boldsymbol\mu)^{\rm T} \boldsymbol ({\mathbf x_i}-\boldsymbol\mu)\right)}$. But in the case that is shown in this tutorial, there is no index I to apply summation.

I would appreciate any insights on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's relatively easy to get mixed up here due to notation. In the case you present from the textbook, they're considering a product of one-dimensional gaussians which are independent from each other, and then writing the form as a multi-dimensional gaussian (since then the covariance matrix of this multidimensional gaussian is exactly $\sigma^2I$). E.g. note that each sample has the form $y_i - (X\beta)_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Taking the product of these distributions yields the multi-dimensional gaussian above.

In your exposition, on the other hand, you're writing a multi-dimensional gaussian which is i.i.d.; this is different than what the textbook is referring to, since the mean should change between distributions (e.g. the samples are independent, but *not* identically drawn, since we're observing different data points with some additional noise, $\varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am still confused. If they derive it by writing it as product what is the index they used? I mean I don't see any variable or index here.

Comment: Let $f(x; \sigma^2)$ be the gaussian PDF, with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, evaluated at $x$ (with appropriate generalization to the multivariate case). Then we can write $\prod_i f(x_i\beta - y; \sigma^2) = f(X\beta - y; \sigma^2I)$. Perhaps it might help clear it up if you show that $\prod_i f(\mu_i; \sigma^2) = f(\mu; \sigma^2 I)$ for general $\mu_i$.

Comment: I did not see the point you mentioned before. Thanks again.

Comment: @Crimson Was I able to answer your question? Sorry, I'm not quite sure if you wanted some more elaboration!

Comment: Yes,  I mean I did not see this step ,$\prod _i f(x_i\beta-y;\sigma^2) - f(X\beta - y ; \sigma^2I)$, before you mentioned. I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Crimson Great! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is the same, only in matrix notation.

First realize that **your** "$X$" is now $Y$ your outcome variable. Now $X$ are the regressors. Next realize that $\mu$ is the regression model, i.e. $X\beta$, as you assume this is the expected value of the model. Next realize, that $Y$ is an $(n,1)$ vector with $n$ observations, $X$ is $(n,d)$ matrix, with $d$ parameters, and $\beta$ is $(d,1)$ vector. Also, by the model assumptions $\Sigma = \sigma^2I \;,\;\Sigma^{-1}=\sigma^{-2}I$.

So the likelihood function is:

$$ \mathcal{L}(\beta, \sigma ^2 | Y, X) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma})^ne^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)}
$$

And if you take the log of it, you get what's in the text book.

You don't need a sum in matrix notation. Notice that $(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)$ is a scalar, which contains the sum you want, i.e. it is equal to $\sum_i^n(y_i-X\beta_i)^2 =\sum_i^n(y_i-\sum_j^d(x_{ij}\beta_j))^2$.

Next you can differentiate by $\beta$ or $\sigma$ to find their MLE.